# First product missing in drop down and only price of first product is being displayed

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have the below code but when i run it it is not doing what i want it to do.

With the code, i have a drop down which lists all the product names from the tblproduct. On selecting the product name, its corresponding price should be displayed in the text field provided where it can be amended and saved. The price of each product is stored in tblretprod. What i am having is the first product name is missing in the drop down but its price is being displayed as default in the text field.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Update product</title>

<SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
function reload(form)
{
var val=form.prod_name.options[form.prod_name.options.selectedIndex].value;
//var description1=form.description.value;
self.location='upd_prod.php?prod_name=' + val;
//+'&description=' +description1;
}

</script>

<link href="CSS/update.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<?php

include('db_connect.php');

@$prod_name=$_GET['prod_name'];

$query=mysql_query("select p.prod_name, pr.prod_price from tblproduct p INNER JOIN tblretprod pr   ON p.prod_id = pr.prod_id");

$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

?>

<div id="stylized" class="myform">

<form id="form" name="upd_prod" method="post" action="updprod.php">

<h2 align="center"><b>- Update Product -</b></h2>

<table width="1000" border="0">
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Product Name</div></td>
<td>
<?PHP 

echo "<select name='prod_name' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\"><option value=''>select one</option>";
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array ($query)) { 
if($row1['0']==@$prod_name){echo "<option selected value='".$row1['0']."'>".$row1['0']." </option>";}
else{echo  "<option value=\"".$row1['0']."\">".$row1['0']."</option>";}
}
echo "</select>";
    ?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div align="right">Product Price (MRU)</div></td>
<td><input type="text" name="prod_price" id="prod_price" value = "<?PHP print $row['prod_price'] ?>"/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p align="center">
 <input type="submit" class="button" name="update" id="update" value="<-- Update product -->" />
</p>

</form>
```

Comment: My question is to know why this issue is occurring and how can it be solved. Thank you for the help.

Comment: once you have used `mysql_fetch_array ` to fetch records then why again using `mysql_fetch_array ` in while loop you have data in `$row` just loop through it why calling twice ??

Comment: As dianuj says - you're calling mysql_fetch_array, and adding the contents into `$row`. Your loop is calling mysql_fetch_array a second time, and setting the contents into `$row1` - so you're only getting the second and later items in your table. But you're pulling price from `$row`, which is why they're all showing the same price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$row=mysql_fetch_array($query);` is not needed.

Calling `mysql_fetch_array` moves the internal result pointer forward -- the subsequent call only gets the 2nd record and higher. Only call it the first time in the loop.

If you need to check whether the query returned rows, use `mysql_num_rows`.

You should also consider switching to mysqli, as mysql has been deprecated.

Lastly, you are lacking a WHERE clause to pull only your selected product. The product you are displaying is being chosen at random.

If you wish to display a single product, and a list all others that are not that product, you should use two separate queries, one that specifies the product and another that excludes it from your list of "other products". Alternatively, you can display all products, but mark the selected product during your loop -- you can save this product to a second variable for use later in the page as well.

Such as:

```
<!-- you beginning HTML -->
<?php

include('db_connect.php');

$prod_name = isset($_GET['prod_name'])?$_GET['prod_name']:"";

$sql = "select p.prod_name, pr.prod_price from tblproduct p INNER JOIN tblretprod pr ON p.prod_id = pr.prod_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {} //No records, do something (exit, die, return, whatever)

?>
<!-- Continue your HTML -->
<?php 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result){
    if($row['prod_name'] == $prod_name) {
        $selected_product = $row;
        echo "<option selected value='".$row['0']."'>".$row['0']." </option>";
    } else {
        echo  "<option value=\"".$row['0']."\">".$row['0']."</option>";
    }
}
?>
<!-- Continue your HTML -->
<td><input type="text" name="prod_price" id="prod_price" 
           value = "<?php print $selected_product['prod_price'] ?>"/></td>    
<!-- Rest of HTML -->
```